# Maven's pom: is dependencies.dependency.version required?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I encountered an issue when working on a multi-module maven & Spring project.
The pom file under root directory has something similar to:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>reporting</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

There is no tag "<version>".

The strange thing is that I had NO problem running this project with command such as:

```
mvn clean install -fn -DskipTests
```

but my colleague ran into an issue similar to "missing dependencies.dependency.version" right after he launched the above command.

Question is, I looked up online, it seemed this "version" tag is mandatory then how come I didn't experience the problem as my colleague did? We worked on the same project, same command, the local repo under ".m2/repository" is the same, what else could be different that produce the different results?

Comment: check this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: The version is probably defined in the `dependencyManagement` section by importing a BOM (possibly in a parent). But if you're using the exact same project, that is not likely.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel everything is possible if parent pom has snapshot version

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Good point, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: From what I experienced when I was working with pom.xml is if you do not define a version tag in your file, it tends to pull the latest version of the jar.
So in order to have more control, and I assume that you do not work with any version that you can get, defining a version tag is more than welcome.

Comment: Please show a log output during the build...second show the full pom files furthermore the given dependency is I suppose a dependency to another child of the multi module build? I'm asking why do you use `-fn` ?